# Oracle SQL Developer: sharing configuration via Dropbox

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dropbox

I would like to share my Oracle SQL Developer configuration across my several computers that use Dropbox.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi Mark. Quick SQL Developer question... how do you find it? Last time I tried it out it didn't have proper file-based development capabilities (i.e. load a SQL file and show the usual navigator for moving around the file). I know it was on the feature list.

Comment: @Nick, they have been releasing new versions fairly frequently with lots of improvements.  What you mention is now incorporated in File/Open, and they also have hooks for incorporating with revision control.  It's definitely worth checking out if you haven't used it in a while.

Comment: I noticed they can open files, but you seem to be left with a big file with no navigation aids. Is that right? I'm used to Toad that parses a file to give package spec/body/functions/procedures. Looked in the features list and it seems to be planned for 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did.

```
#!/bin/bash

# share sqldeveloper config via dropbox
# this is for sqldeveloper 1.5.4, change your paths as necessary
# strace or dtruss sqldeveloper to see what config files are accessed

ITEMS="
o.ide.11.1.1.0.22.49.48/preferences.xml
o.ide.11.1.1.0.22.49.48/settings.xml
o.jdeveloper.cvs.11.1.1.0.22.49.48/preferences.xml
o.jdeveloper.subversion.11.1.1.0.22.49.48/preferences.xml
o.jdeveloper.vcs.11.1.1.0.22.49.48/preferences.xml
o.sqldeveloper.11.1.1.59.40/preferences.xml
o.sqldeveloper.11.1.1.59.40/product-preferences.xml
"

INST=~/Library/Application\ Support/SQL\ Developer/system1.5.4.59.40
DROP=~/Dropbox/Library/SQL\ Developer/system1.5.4.59.40

# note, you can zap your configuration if you are not careful.
# remove these exit lines when you're sure you understand what's
# going on.

exit

# copy from real folder to dropbox
for i in $ITEMS; do
    echo uncomment to do this once to bootstrap your dropbox
    #mkdir -p "`dirname "$DROP/$i":`"
    #cp -p "$INST/$i" "$DROP/$i"
done

exit

# link from dropbox to real folder
for i in $ITEMS; do
    rm "$INST/$i"
    ln -s "$DROP/$i" "$INST/$i"
done
```

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone comes here looking for the location of user configured options like me, they are hiding here:

```
%appdata%\SQL Developer\
```

This is useful to know when copying your preferences to a new computer. If you are looking for the connection settings, search for `connections.xml` in that directory. There are also some other configuration files here that you may need:

```
sqldeveloper.conf – <sqldeveloper dir>\sqldeveloper\bin\
ide.conf – <sqldeveloper dir>\ide\bin\
```

This is for Oracle SQL Developer 3.

Answer (score 1):

Simple sharing SQLDeveloper config on Dropbox, the easiest way on MACOSX is to

```
cd ~/Dropbox
mkdir -p Library/SQLDeveloper
cp -rp ~/.sqldeveloper/* Library/SQLDeveloper/
mv ~/.sqldeveloper ~/remove_when_sure_sqldeveloper
ln -sf $PWD/Library/SQLDeveloper ~/.sqldeveloper
```

Do this on your most important machine and on the machine on which to share only do

```
cd ~/Dropbox
mv ~/.sqldeveloper ~/remove_when_sure_sqldeveloper
ln -sf $PWD/Library/SQLDeveloper ~/.sqldeveloper
```

This works like a charm.